# UIScrollview scrolled unexpected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

first I add a scrollView to my viewConrtoller ,and set it's `contentSize = (kScreenWidth,0),contentOffset = (0,0);`

then I pushed a new  viewConrtoller,when the  new  viewConrtoller poped back the contentOffset of the  scrollView has been set (0,-64)

I found this scene in the delegate method :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

   NSLog(@"scrollView.offset = %@ contensize = %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset),NSStringFromCGSize(scrollView.contentSize));

}
```

I did nothing but it happened ... I  don't known how could it  happened

anyone who can help me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Show your code, where have you wrote the code for scrollView

Comment: You need to set the scrollview's contentOffset appropriately in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solutions:

1. You need to set the scrollview's contentOffset appropriately in viewWillAppear:
2. Disable automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ViewController will try to adjust insets of its first subview which is an UIScrollView. Add this in your `viewWillAppear` method.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```